# Returning object for method call expression doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I have the following return line in a "BindSetMember" method:

```
return new DynamicMetaObject(Expression.TypeAs(methodCall, binder.ReturnType), restrictions)
```

Which doesn't box the returned 'bool' value from the 'methodCall' expression (gives a type conversion error).  I expected that the return value (bool) for the expression method 'methodCall' would be boxed into an object type (since the method returns 'bool', but the DLR callsite expects 'object'; the specification says boxing should occur when 'TypeAs' is used).  I've tried "Expression.Convert" also, but I keep getting a type conversion error.  Why isn't this working?  Am I being forced to create a lambda expression to forward the call!? :(

Thanks.

(FYI: This question is similar to an existing one, but I am asking a specific question here for a possible alternate solution)

Comment: You're saying the method that this return statement is for is supposed to return a bool? Like `public bool BindSetMember(object methodCall, object restrictions){ return new DynamicMetaObject(Expression.TypeAs(methodCall, binder.ReturnType), restrictions); }`? If that is the case, a DynamicMetaObject is not a bool.

Comment: No, forget about the method the line is in.  I said "methodCall", which is a reference to the variable in the line.

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding. I'm still confused, though. The Expression.TypeAs method's first parameter is expecting an Expression, not an object. If I'm still completely off base, I shall refrain from commenting as at that point I've concluded I have no idea what I'm talking about.

Comment: LOL. ;)  Sorry, "methodCall" is a method call expression.  Sorry I didn't mention that. I'll update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.  I had thought the conversion issue was due to the return type of the method expression, but I forgot I had a conversion expression for one of the method parameters as well - and it was that conversion that was in error.  I have an explicit conversion to a value type from a given object, but upon further investigation, it turns out you have to convert "object" to the actual type before implicit conversions will work. ;)

So, in summary, if you have a method that returns something other than "object", simply use "Expression.Convert" or "Expression.TypeAs" to convert/box the return type into an object type. ;)

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.

Comment: Thanks.  Working with expressions is a real mind bender. LOL.